# grails install-templates does not create web.xml file

Tags: tomcat, grails, tomcat7, web.xml

I am using version 3.0.11 of Grails and when I create a new application and then run the`grails install-templates` command, I see a bunch of new (gsp & groovy) files being generated but no `src/templates/war/web.xml` file, which I need to edit in order to make my application distributable.

Anyone know what the issue is?

Thanks,

Seán

Comment: Ok, so I now see here: https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/upgrading.html that these files are no longer present in Grails 3.x and that Grails 3.0 no longer requires web.xml - customizations are instead done via Spring, which leads me to ask are Grails 3.0 applications distributable by default?